# SQL query in query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a small problem in PHP.

I have a car table, and it has 4 columns: id, manufacturer, model, detail.

I want to get a list of manufacturer in car table, and after having selected a manufacturer, I want to get the list of car models of that manufacturer, after having selected a model, I want to get the list of details about that model.

How can I make it work with tag "select" and "option" ?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Use `JOIN` to get the related rows between different tables.

Comment: it's not homework

Comment: There's no need to beg or plead, but there is a need for *code* you've written. Anything is better than nothing.

Comment: actually, it's in a PHP project, I have written the code at the bottom

Comment: Pls provide more details about tables in database

Comment: TABLE car (id, manufacturer, model, details), TABLE tyre(id,size, price) and TABLE tyre_used_for(car_id, tyre_id).

Comment: @tadman:  thanks for editting my question, I'm trying to make my own website, it's about music, coding is not my skill, i wonder if my solution or my code is good,   can you help me?

Comment: That's a pretty fast pivot from cars to music. In either case you'll need to understand the principles of [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) when designing a relational schema. Once you've got a handle on the basics a lot of this will make intuitive sense.

Comment: @tadman: Yes, I'm learning some more about the principles, I intend to make my web as the same way of making car-tyre web: I store some artists , each of them plays some kinds of music, each kind of music has some pieces of music. Now I just don't know how to write the PHP code like this web www.thegioilop.com.vn - Tìm lốp theo xe

Comment: Having done a lot of music database work, that's really not a good comparison. Songs have one or more composers, zero or more performers,  and appear on zero or more albums. Cars are made by one company and can take multiple tire sizes from multiple vendors where tires and rims must be the same size. Front and rear tires can even be different sizes.

Comment: maybe I need to solve the simple problem before going to the harder or complex problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its really bad idea to put it in one SQL query, you better to select * from car to a one array and use it as you want.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I have 3 tag "option" in my PHP script. The first tag is for finding manufacturer, the second is for finding  models of that manufacturer, and the third is for finding details of that model.

Comment: If I got it right you have something about:
Client clicked on the manufacturer
After that he got a reply with models
And after that he can choose a details (coz it depends on year etc)
Is that right?

Comment: You dont really need a MySQL in this case.
You can do everything by JavaScript, better performance for your server.

Comment: Yes, but how can I do it by MySQL, I don't know about JavaScript

Comment: select model from car where manufacturer=mysql_real_escape_string("$_GET[manufacturer]");

after 
select detail from car where model=mysql_real_escape_string("$_GET[manufacturer]") and manufacturer=mysql_real_escape_string("$_GET[manufacturer]");

just use a manual, its simple and any PHP/MYSQL manual contains it.